# replace element when drag in drop area

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, cordova, drag-and-drop

I am trying to write 1 app that have some "p" tag can drag and 1 "div" tag as drop area.

When i drag "p" tag into drop area they append in drop area.

I can drag 10 "p" tag and more, but i want when i drag new "p" tag, the old "p" tag must remove or is replaced

Please give me some advice! thanks a lot

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>jQuery UI Touch Punch - Mobile Device Touch Event Support for jQuery UI</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
    <link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/jquery-ui1.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>body { background:#fff; font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }</style>

    <script src="js/cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <script>
        $(function() {

          var chu = ["aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee","fff","ggg","hhh","jjj","kkk","lll","mmm"];
          $("p").text(function(){
              return chu[ Math.floor((Math.random()*chu.length)+0)];
            });
          var c = 0;

          $('#dragSource p').draggable({
              helper: function(){
              var selected = $('#dragSource').parents('p');
              if (selected.length === 0) {
                selected = $(this);
              }
              var container = $('<div/>').attr('id', 'draggingContainer');
              container.append(selected.clone());
              return container;
            }
          });

          $('#c').droppable({
              tolerance: 'pointer',
              drop: function(event, ui){
                  $(this).append(ui.helper.children());
                  c++;
                  while(c == 2) {
                      $(this).find('p').remove();
                      c = 0;
                  }
            }
          });

        });
        </script>
      <div class="demo">
      <div id="dragSource" class="droppableContainer">
          <p></p>
          <p></p>
          <p></p>
          <p></p>
      </div>
      <input id="canvasDraw" type="button" value="New Game"/>
      <ul id="c" class="droppableContainer" style="display:inline;border:1px solid #d3d3d3;width: 150px; height: 150px;float:left;vertical-align: middle;">
      </ul>
      </div><!-- End demo -->
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Edit:**

i changed drop area (from "ul" tag into "input" tag) but it's cobe don't work; please give me some advice! i am new and know very little about web!

this is my change:

```
<input id="c" class="droppableContainer" style="display:inline;border:1px solid #d3d3d3;width: 150px; height: 150px;float:left;vertical-align: middle;"/>
```

and

```
 $('#c').droppable({
          tolerance: 'pointer',
          drop: function(event, ui){
              $(this).disable();
              $(this).find('p').remove();
              $(this).append(ui.helper.children());
              htmlOfDroppedElement = $(ui.draggable).html();
              pElementToBeReplaced = $(this).find('p');
              $(pElementToBeReplaced).html(htmlOfDroppedElement);
        }
      });
```

**Edit 2:**

I already do it

```
htmlOfDroppedElement = $(ui.draggable).html();
                $(this).val(htmlOfDroppedElement);
```

Comment: which p tag do you want removed? from the ones that are draggable or the ones that have been dropped before?

Comment: i want replace that dropped before by that dropped now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#c').droppable({
    tolerance: 'pointer',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            htmlOfDroppedElement = $(ui.draggable).html();
            pElementToBeReplaced = $(this).find('p');
            $(pElementToBeReplaced).html(htmlOfDroppedElement);
        }
    });
```

Here, I am just replacing the html within the `<p>` element of the droppable div with the `<p>` element of the draggable div.